# Display resolutions missing after upgrade to Ubuntu 12-10

Tags: display

I recently upgraded my dual-boot HP laptop (dv7-3060us, 17.3" display) from ubuntu 12-4 to 12-10.  After the upgrade, only three (3) resolutions are available (800x600, 1024x768, and 1152x864, all 4:3 resolutions), none of which are 16:9.  Everything worked properly in 12-04.  The display adapter is ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4530.
Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions about how to correct this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That thing where AMD no longer supports Radeon HD 4000 on X 1.13, I should think. unixmen.com may have [a solution for you](http://www.unixmen.com/ubuntu-12-10-and-amd-catalyst-problem-solved/).

Answer (score 0):

**Create the modeline with cvt**

> cvt 1920 1080

The output:#

```
1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHzModeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

**Create the new mode with xrandr**

Take the modeline output from above and append it tot eh xrandr --newmode command. Note I had to drop the refresh rate "_60.00" from the new mode name for this to work. Without dropping the refresh rate the command refuse to work.

> xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

**Check the new resolution mode was created**

```
xrandr
```

The output:

```
 Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
 VGA1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y
 axis) 0mm x 0mm    1920x1080      60.0      1024x768       60.0 *+    
 800x600        60.3     56.2      848x480        60.0      640x480 59.9
 HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
 DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) HDMI2
 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) HDMI3
 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) DP2
 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) DP3
```

disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

**Add the mode to the config** 
For me this step also switch the monitor straight to the new resolution mode

> xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1920x1080"

**For persistence edit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf**

> sudo vi /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf

Update it to read as follows, note I added two resolution modes. I used cvt both times to generate the modelines which I then manually addded to the config file (see those lines in blue):

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor0"
  Modeline "1920x1200"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
  Modeline "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

EndSection
Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Screen0"
  Device "VGA1"
  Monitor "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1200" "1920x1080" "1024x768"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Again I had to drop the refresh rates from the mode names, without dropping the refresh rates when rebooting I just received a black screen without a terminal, when dropping to the terminal I received errors related to parsing the monitor config.

Also check that the identifier in the screen section matches that shown in the xrandr output i.e. Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current....

**Save the config from within vi [ESC] :wq! [Enter] and reboot**

**If anything goes awry** 
on reboot simply drop to a terminal and remove the monitor config file

> sudo rm /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf